# Sibling components interaction in Angular2. Which technique to use?

Tags: angular

### Some info

I'm new at Angular2.
I'm developing my first application, mainly as a hobby.
The web application requirements that i've propuse are something like [Plaxo](http://plaxo.com), a personal agenda. My "problem" is in the **address book section**:

Here's a screenshot of the **address book section**. I want to do something similar.
[image: Plaxo's adress book]
As you can see Plaxo organizes contacts by group (first column).
You can pick a contact that belongs to the selected group (second column).
And you can see the selected contact's information and modify, delete, export...

**So, how do i want to organise this?**

Each column should be a different component. First the *group's-list.component*, then the *contacts-list.component* and finally the *contact-info.component*.

### My question:

In angular 2 there are several ways to implement components interaction. But in this case, unfortunately, components are not parent and child like in the approaches listed at [Angular's Component interaction Cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html) and approached used in [Angular's quickstart tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/).

**So, which would be the best approach to communicate between this sibling components?**

- Input binding: Just use the parent of these three components and pass them the data that the have to show.
- Parameterized routes: Use the angular router and pass some data through URL. 
  For example: *myapp.com/addressbook/[SOME_GROUP_ID]/[SOME_CONTACT_ID]* (myapp.com/addressbook/3/23) Group 3, contact 23.
- Others...

PD: If my question isn't clear, links to examples are welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a template variable at the elements and refer to each other

```
<a-cmp #a (someEvent)="b.doSomething()">
<b-cmp #b (someOtherEvent)="a.doSomething()">
```

or you can use a shared service that you provide at a common parent and inject to both siblings.

Comment: I think you mean (someEvent) and (someOtherEvent) instead of [someEvent] and [someOtherEvent] ?

Answer (score 0):

**`@Input API`** is used when you have `Parent-Child` scenario. For sibling components, you may think of using **`SharedService`** for data exchange.